What happened to "custom-urls" in RedStone, and why is the related manifest updater unavailable?
I'm trying to work with custom-urls in RedStone, but I couldn't find any relevant documentation in the current RedStone docs.
Interestingly, I came across this tutorial from two years ago, where the developer demonstrates the "custom-url" option in the RedStone documentation dropdown menu. However, it seems this feature has since disappeared from the docs.
Additionally, the link mentioned in the video (https://custom-urls-manifest-updater.redstone.finance/) now returns a 503 Service Unavailable error.
Has this feature been deprecated or moved?
If so, is there an alternative or an updated way to achieve similar functionality?
Any guidance or clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Since it's a very specific question, try asking also in the discord https://discord.gg/Gyr5JQVF
